# Script to create new files with content recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, inkscape

I have a tree of folders where every folder contains between two and three jpg files. As I have plenty folders, I would like to develop a script to create recursively an Inkscape file in every folder containing the jpg files in it, and renaming the svg file with the name of the containing folder. How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find directories with JPG files and run `inkscape` on them:

```
find . -type d \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*.jpg; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} ';' \
    -exec sh -c 'inkscape --export-plain-svg="$1/${1##*/}.svg" "$1"/*.jpg' sh {} ';'
```

This will look for directories under the current directory. If the directory contains at least one `.jpg` file, `inkscape` is invoked on this directory, picking up all `.jpg` files from within it and exporting an SVG file into it, with the name of the directory as its filename.

The output filename is constructed as `$1/${1##*/}.svg` where `$1` is the first command line argument to the `sh -c` script (this is the path to the directory with the `.jpg` files), and where `${1##*/}` will strip the path from the directory and leave just the directory name.

This is untested in as far as I don't have `inkscape` and I'm not familiar with the program (apart from reading its manual).

Given the following directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dirA
|   `-- 1
|       |-- file.jpg
|       |-- image.jpg
|       `-- picture.jpg
`-- dirB
    |-- 2
    |   |-- file.jpg
    |   |-- image.jpg
    |   `-- picture.jpg
    |-- 3
    |   |-- file.jpg
    |   `-- image.jpg
    `-- 4
        |-- file.jpg
        `-- image.jpg

6 directories, 10 files
```

This is what would have been executed:

```
inkscape --export-plain-svg=./dirA/1/1.svg ./dirA/1/file.jpg ./dirA/1/image.jpg ./dirA/1/picture.jpg
inkscape --export-plain-svg=./dirB/2/2.svg ./dirB/2/file.jpg ./dirB/2/image.jpg ./dirB/2/picture.jpg
inkscape --export-plain-svg=./dirB/3/3.svg ./dirB/3/file.jpg ./dirB/3/image.jpg
inkscape --export-plain-svg=./dirB/4/4.svg ./dirB/4/file.jpg ./dirB/4/image.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda for your quick answer. At first, it seemed to work. The script created the svg file keeping the name of the containing folder. However, only 1 jpg file was included and not all the files contained in the folder. What might be the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: @antecessor This may be something to do with how `inkscape` works when you give it multiple input files. I don't use this program. Could you tell me what the command should look like for a single folder?

Comment: I don't really know how the command should look like... I've been checking the manual and I don't really know where to look at... I ran Inkscape from my terminal but nothing appears on it when importing images from the GUI...